# Best way to recover a server from a client's disconnect

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I've written a tcp server in Java. It spawns worker instances (Runnable) and listens for incoming tcp connection. Upon connection from a client, it will take in data from the client and does its own processing.

Of late, I noticed that upon client disconnection, the entire server will crash with error java.net.SocketException: Connection reset when the client disconnects or quits. This was when I realised I hadn't tested the tcp server thoroughly for all instances of failure.

I looked into the code and noticed that the tcp server will crash at this line while((bytesRead.... -1) in the worker instance

```
final int BUFFSIZE = 65535;
int bytesRead;
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFSIZE];
din = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

while ((bytesRead = din.read(buffer)) != -1) {   //tcp server crashes at this line if client quits or disconnects.
// worker does its job.
}
```

I've been pondering about the best way to close worker instance without causing a crash on the tcp server. I don't have access to the client source code to modify anything on their end.

Any thoughts?

Bregs
Yakult121

Comment: It's called `try {} catch () {}`...

Comment: Hi nfechner, how can i incorporate try catch into the while statement?

Comment: Not sure about Java read(), (hence this is a comment), but in some other languages, the read() returns early with bytesRead of 0. Since you are comparing with -1, the worker code would then execute with no bytes - almost certainly raising an exception somewhere within.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network I/O should be done within a try/catch block if you want to handle exceptions.

Comment: Hi David, how should i incorporate the try/catch block into the while statement? I'm confused.

Comment: It depends on the structure of the code. But you will want every network I/O statement to be inside a 'try' block. Perhaps one big one. Perhaps lots of little ones. It depends.

Comment: Hmmm ok. I'll probably stay with the same code and test a try/catch encompassing the while loop.

Answer (score 2):

This line should throw an IOException if the connection is closed. Just make sure to catch the IOException and return from the `run()` method of your Runnable when it occurs. This will stop the thread handling this client connection.

You must have done something incorrectly if it craches the whole server, though. This probably means you don't have a thread per client connection, but rather a single thread handling the clients sequentially, one at a time. Post the server code for more information.

Comment: Hi JB Nizet, I will try to post more information later this evening after I get home. I had tried to connect to the tcp server with at least two concurrent client and it runs fine. But when i close one of the two clients, the TCP server dies.

Answer (score 1):

figured out the problem. Writing down what i did for any person looking to solve the same problem.

```
private boolean isStopped = false;

while (!isStopped()) {
   try {
      while ((bytesRead = din.read(buffer)) != -1) {   
         // worker does its job.
      }
   }
   catch (IOException ex) {
      System.out.println("Exception called! Most likely due to client disconnect!");
      stop();
   }
}

public boolean isStopped() {
    return this.isStopped;
} 

public synchronized void stop(){
    this.isStopped = true;
}
```

Comment: You can get rid of isStopped(), stop(), and this.isStopped() by just using a break statement. Don't make life harder than it is. Also when you catch an exception, always print *its* message. Don't just make up your own.